# looping hashmap in arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have an `ArrayList` containing `HashMap`s. It is defined as follow:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersList1;
```

I have a list which has set of items. When I click any option in the list it will get the name of the item and store in the `String`. I have looped the `HashMap` as below in the code.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView text=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category);
        String item = text.getText().toString();

        for (HashMap<String, String> entry : usersList1) {                                 
            if (entry.containsKey(item)) {                                   
                for (String key : entry.keySet()) {
                    if (entry.get(key).equals("")) {
                        System.out.println(key);
                    }
                    else if (!entry.get(key).equals("")) {
                        System.out.println(entry.get(key));
                    }
                }                    
            }                                                      
        }       
    }
});
```

My doubt is when i check for the null it is displaying both (key) and (entry.get(key)) but i want to display key only if its value is null else (entry.get(key)).For example in the array i have jj key with empty value and another with a value. One with empty value should print key and one without empty valueshould print the value.how can this be achieved

My array looks like this in log

```
[{jj=},{FBDF=DFHBDF},{jj=abc}]
```

How can I achieve this? Code for this would be helpful

Comment: use `.equals`. for string comparison. What is `userList1`?

Comment: i tried with .equals too. but did work. usersLIst1 is array list

Comment: also why do you need to loop through the list. i guess you want to get the items at the clicked row? you can use `TextUtils.isEmpty`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: what is the problem now? and what is the expected output?

Comment: when i select first jj item in the list it is checking both if loop and displaying both key and value.but for the first jj it should display only key. both jj are getting considered here which i dont want to happen

Comment: first you can use `HashMap<String,String> map = (HashMap)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)`  then get the the value .

Answer (score 0):

```
if (entry.get(key).equals("")) {
    System.out.println(key);
}
else if (!entry.get(key).equals("")) {
    System.out.println(entry.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (Map<String,String> map: userList1) {
    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entryMap: map.entrySet()) {
        //Your code or whatever here...
        if (entryMap.getKey().equals(item)) {

        }
    }
}
```